# Org mode keyword completion with pcomplete showing uppercase and lowercase duplicates

Tags: org-mode, org-export, completion

Invoking `complete-symbol` after `#+` in an Org buffer uses `pcomplete` to display the following completion candidates list:

```
ORG:
org:
BIND:
bind:
DATE:
date:
etc.
```

I would like to remove the duplication of uppercase and lowercase candidates (preferably keeping the lowercase candidates). I have tried `(setq completion-ignore-case t)`, but this doesn't change it.

My guess is that there is a variable containing this list of candidates for org export keywords, and I need to find it and remove the uppercase elements.